# Hide html elements after a key is pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if there was a way to hide header tags, images, divs etc from showing on an html page after a certain key is pressed. I am making a hangman game and when the player loses or wins, I display a message with a header tag. If the user presses Y, the game restarts but I dont how to make the header tag that ask "play again" to disappear once the player chooses Y

Comment: Sure there's a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there are several methods for doing this I am just showing here a keypress  example for **Enter** button click lets try the below code

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {    //for enter button
    $('#div_name').hide();
}
 });
```

Comment: Hmm i will look into the hide method. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy with jQuery.

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which)); 
});
```

Run the fiddle, click on the output section, and you can test it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/69vm21ou/

Comment: Im not allowed to use jquery in my project